# Is it possible AngularJS acess request and session scope of my application?

Tags: angularjs, session, request, server-side

When I make a request and set on the request and session scope (server side) some attributes. I would like to know if is it possible to get with AngularJS these attributes at my server side.

Comment: can put session variables into json response if that's what you mean

Comment: What server technology are you using?  Is there a login process?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for any "session integration" for authentication purposes, take a look at [Spring Session](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session) in conjunction with [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). I wrote a little [sample application](https://github.com/ghillert/botanic-ng) that illustrates how to integrate [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) with Spring Security by exposing the session id as an HTTP header (x-auth-token). The corresponding blog post is **[here](http://www.hillert.blogspot.com/2014/09/secure-your-angularjs-apps-with-spring-session.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, typically one can do as [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) said very easily when performing an asynchronous login.  Just return some JSON containing upon a successful login.

I store the returned JSON in a ".value" service:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.value('appData', {})
.factory('authService', ['$http', '$q', 'appData',
    function authService($http, $q, appData) {
        var setAppData = function(data) {
            angular.copy(data, appData);
        };
        return {
            login: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.post('/auth', data)
                .success(function(response){
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                    setAppData(response);
                })
                .error(function(reason){
                    deferred.reject(reason);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
            logout: function() {
               //...http call to logout
               setAppData({});
            }
        };
    }
])
;
```